# JPanel taking whole JFrame size. BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing

I have problem with my `JPanel`, which alone takes the whole `JFrame` space.
I want to add two `JPanel`'s in a single `JFrame`. I'm helping myself with eclipse plugin WindowMaker, but I also tried to code the layout by hand - to no avail. There's no way that I can resize my `JPanel` e.g. make it 50% of its size.
I read about this case and tried to understand LayoutManagers. But even if I put my `JLabel` to corner or any specific side, nothing changes so far.
Can somebody help me with that?

Code sample:
private JPanel contentPane;

```
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GUI() {

    setTitle("GALAXY INVADERS: CASTELO EDITION");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setBounds(200, 100, 1000, 600);


    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // init of the Panel
    contentPane = new MyPanel2();

    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(300, 400));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

}
```

`MyPanel2` is a class which extends JPanel.

Comment: Judging from the title of your GUI, it appears you are making a game. If so, I encourage you to have a [proper game loop](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0). (If I'm wrong, tell me and I will delete this comment)

Comment: I think you're confused what `content pane` actually is.  Work through [Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) tutorials.

Comment: @JoshM Yes it's a game. I have overrided painting method which repaints whole game.

Comment: You shouldn't need to override any sort of painting method to create a game. Look at the link I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BorderLayout` has 5 available positions onto which components are added...

By default, the `CENTER` position will occupy the whole available space of the container.

Try placing you other components into different positions or try a different layout manager.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details...

Comment: What should I fix then? Code sample?

Comment: You can use `add(component, BorderLayout.NORTH)` for example, to add the component to the `NORTH` position of the container or you could take a look at the link and find a layout manager that better meets your needs.  If you only want to add two components that share 50% of the available width or height, you could use a `GridLayout`

Comment: It stills add another JPanel on the old one. I want to have two separate panels.

Comment: Then you're adding your panels to each other, not the frame. Try not using `setContentPane` and simply add your panels to the frame...